# I am trying to update my post on my MongoDB database, but it shows this : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'updateOne')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

### I am trying to update my post on my MongoDB database, but it shows: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'updateOne')

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Post = require("../moduls/Post");

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const newpost = Post(req.body);
    try {
        const savedPost = await newpost.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedPost);

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error)
    }

});
```

**Here I try to write a code for updating my post. But it doesn't work.**

```
//Update Post
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    // try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    if (post.userId === req.body.userId) {
        await post.updateOne({ $set: req.body })
    }
    else {
        res.status(403).json("You can't update it")
    }

    // } catch (error) {
    //     res.status(500).json("Internal Error")
    // }
})
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I guess you should add additional check for the post to exist before updating it. if(post && (post.userId === req.body.userId)).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, there are a few things that are wrong in your code:

- Add always a check that the operation has succeeded before moving on.
- Use Post instead of post to perform operations on.(Post Mongoose model instead of an instance of a Post)
- In your case you can use `findOneAndUpdate` no need to find the corresponding Post first and then update after.

```js
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const postUpdated = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
                userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userId) // assuming it is saved as a mongo id
            },
            req.body,
            { new: true }
        );

        if (!postUpdated) {
            throw new Error('could not update Post');
        }
        res.json(postUpdated);
    } catch (e) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

As an addition:

- Your commented error handling is actually needed, due to the fact that Express does not handle the returned promise for you.(This is what makes you get a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`)
- Your code also does not provide any form of validation of the incoming request, you might want to consider checking first what data you are receiving from the client before inserting it into the database.